# Send FORMDATA OBJECT to a MYSQL Table using Vanilla JS

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, post, multipartform-data

Is it possible to send a JS FormData Object into a MYSQL Table using vanilla JS.

I have a HTML form that accepts various user input. I am using the JS FormData Object to grab all data from the form.

I converted this FormData Object in to a JSON format in order to save to it to localstorage. This works perfectly and I can console.log both the original FormData object and the new JSON object.

This is what I achieved so far:

```
// Create a variable for the select of the form tag
  const form = document.querySelector('form');

// Add an event listener for submit button
  form.addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
    e.preventDefault(); // Prevent form refresh on submit
      const fd = new FormData(form); // Create a new array of arrays (formData object) and store it in a variable

// Object fromEntries Method: Object data stored in formatted in key value pairs
    const obj = Object.fromEntries(fd); // Returns object values
    console.log(obj);

// JSON to Local Storage: Convert object to JSON format and store in localstorage
  const json = JSON.stringify(obj); // Convert object data into JSON format and store it in a variable
    localStorage.setItem('form', json); // Store JSON formatted data to localstorage
```

I have a connection to the MYSQL database but need to figure out how to send FomrData object  (original or JSON object) to an existing MYSQL table.

Is this possible using pure JS / node.js and SQL? I need to translate / sync the key values pairs in the object to the table columns and INSERT. I am searching for examples of this but without much success.

Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: you can send the json as it is to a text or json column, varchar too but it is more size limited

Comment: Thank you but how? Is there no function required to do this?

Comment: no that is the same as sending a string

Comment: You want to store the file in the database, am I right? If I am right, my suggestion could be, if you want to store the file to database instead of storing that file to database, store the file in filesystem and store that path to database.

Comment: Bennison, You are correct. All I want to do is store the Object in MYSQL table. I have a connection to the DB, I have the object, I just need to find the approach and syntax to make this happen.